# How to enable the tab while selecting the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have got a task to do Jquery tab. On this when I select a check box the corresponding tab must show on the page and others must be disabled.Multiple checkbox is also allowed.Then corresponding pages must be enabled.

My code is

```
<html !doctype>
<head>
<title>JqueryMenu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
  });
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
});
});
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nithin</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Vipin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sachin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ganguly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Nithin</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Vipin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Sachin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Ganguly</p>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-1" value="1">tabs-1 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2">tabs-2 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3">tabs-3 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-4" value="4">tabs-4 
<br>
 </body>
 </html>
```

How can I do this? You can see the demo http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add condition below

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/5/)